# Как в Laravel 8 сделать переадресацию на другую страницу сразу после авторизации?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

В `RouteServiceProvider` написал `public const HOME = '/welcome';` Но сюда направляет, только если пользователь не аунтифицирован. А мне нужно направлять сюда сразу после регистрации или авторизации (сейчас перенаправляет в корневую директорию "/".

Не пойму уже куда копать?

Comment: Для этого есть прокладка [RedirectIfAuthenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov У меня эта прокладка не работает. Даже не знаю почему. Но сработала эта функция: public function authenticated()
    {
        if(Auth::id())
        {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return redirect()->route('welcome');
    }

Comment: Для того чтобы она сработала она должна быть включена в Kernel.